# How to update event.target.value on keypress?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working to make postal code validation but I am not able to get `updatedValue` using `event.target.value` its showing `oldValue`

HTML code:

```
<input type="text"  style="color:black !important;width:100%;" (keypress)="numericOnly($event);" name="fname" [(ngModel)]='value' autofocus>
```

.ts file

```
 numericOnly(event): boolean {
        console.log("element", event);
        console.log('element.value', event.target.value);
        let patt = new RegExp("^[a-z A-Z 0-9]*-?[a-z A-Z 0-9]*$");
        console.log('this.value', this.value);
        let result = patt.test(event.target.value);
        console.log('result', result)
        if (result == false) {
            // event.target.value = this.value
            // this.value = event.target.value;
            const val = <string>event.target.value
            if (val && val.length > 0) {
                this.value =  event.target.value;
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

when I trying to access the target value using    `event.target.value` its giving oldVlaue
i want to get recently typed value on `keypress` event.whenever I used `keyup` event its updating `ngModel` which I don't want.

[image]

Comment: `keypress` fires when a key is pressed down - that does not necessarily mean that the field value has actually changed at that point already. Either work with the actual key code you get from the event object, or use a different event (MDN already says this is deprecated, and you should rather use `beforeinput` or `keydown` instead, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event - but those will probably have the same issue, you might need to use `keyup` if you actually want to read the updated field value at this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change `[(ngModel)]='value'` to `[ngModel]='value'` so that the model would not be updated on changes and then use `(keyup)`.

Template code:

```
<input type="text" style="color:black !important;width:100%;" (keyup)="numericOnly($event);" name="fname" [ngModel]='value' autofocus>
```

As long as your `numericOnly` method updates your model (`this.value`) when the condition is met (as is doing now) you don't need the two-way data binding of ngModel.